# Velocity of player not smoothing when changing directions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**GOAL**
So I'm making a 2D platformer in Unity with C#.
I want the character to slow down then accelerate in the opposite direction when the player inputs the opposite direction. This usually does happen.

**PROBLEM**
However sometimes the character just immediately switches directions without slowing etc.

[image: GIF of bug]

(It happens twice in this clip)

Since it happens with what seems to be no pattern, I assume it may have something to do with FixedUpdate or input? But I really don't know.

**CODE**
GitHub repo of all code : https://github.com/LeoWB/DOFE_Game

Comment: Probably not related but `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` already returns a `float` (== `System.Single`) .. what is the `Convert.ToSingle` good for?

Comment: Generally speaking, I think it is a good practice to put any inputs in the Update, since the inputs are updates every frame. Try that and let us know!

Comment: @kostis1101 The `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` is already in update :/

Comment: Why don't you try to put the code for smoothing the movement in the Update?

Comment: @derHugo I want it to be controller compatible but dont want the player to be able to move at half speed if the stick is moved halfway

Comment: @kostis1101 the bug still happens :/

Comment: @LWB doesn't explain why you try to convert a `float` to a `float` though ... sounds like you rather wanted `Math.Sign`?